How to parse NS section of DNS query?
So I am following this guide DNS Resolver in C to mimic DNS query in C , by following it I am able to fetch A records successfully
But when I change the query type to 2 , that is NS record query , I do not get the complete answer
  header.qdcount=htons(1);
   header.ancount=htons(3); //number of NS records I want
   
   
   dns_question_t question;
   question.dnstype=htons(2);//query type is 2 , that is NS record
   question.dnsclass = htons(1);//class Internet

When I completely dump the response buffer from DNS server , I get someting like this

4▒▒.cloudflare.com▒
qns3▒
▒
qns4▒
▒
qns5▒
▒
qns6▒
▒
qns7▒


How am I suppose to parse the answer part of the buffer ?
Here is the structure I am using for "ANSWER" section
typedef struct {
  uint16_t compression;
  uint16_t type;
  uint16_t class;
  uint32_t ttl;
  uint16_t length;
  char name[];
} __attribute__((packed)) dns_record_ns_t;

From reading RFC 1035 I got to know that it could be due to name compression , but when I check  the
first two bits of compression , they both are not set , because if compressed , then they should be set bits.
for (int i = 0; i < ntohs (response_header->ancount); i++)
  {
    uint16_t x = ntohs(records[i].compression);
    printf ("%" PRId16 "\n",((x>>1)&1));
    printf ("%" PRId16 "\n",((x>>2)&1));


  }

Edit:
So I read about DNS name compression from RFC 1035 , and here is how I am approaching to decompressing the compressed names.
The structure
typedef struct {
 uint16_t compression;
  uint16_t type;
  uint16_t class;
  uint32_t ttl;
  uint16_t length;
  uint16_t name;
} __attribute__((packed)) dns_record_ns_t;

But the catch is , when I extract the bits of name using
 for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
 {
   printf("%d",x&1);
    x=x>>1;
  }

Here is  one of the result
0010000011100000
but the catch is , the starting address of my response buffer from DNS
is  1482892848
So if I convert the first 14 bits , from right , I get an offset way above my buffer size as it is  uint8_t response[512]
Where am I mistaking ?

The data in an NS response is a series of labels, similar to the name field in an A record query (a length byte followed by that many text bytes). You need to loop through these strings until you get to the 0 length.

Labels can also be references to earlier names. So qns3.cloudflare.com is represented as the string qns3 followed by a back-reference to cloudflare.com from the question field.

@Barmar can you please suggest what should be an ideal message structure ? I mean if I get the response should I first check for compression byte to be set and then proceed ?

@Barmar for eg I am getting two zero bits , that mean it is a label , but in RFC 1035 , I cant find a description of how a label is structured

It's in Section 3.1: Domain names in messages are expressed in terms of a sequence of labels.
Each label is represented as a one octet length field followed by that
number of octets.

And 4.1.4 explains how compression is used in in domain names.

@Barmar I have updated my situation in the question, can you please guide ?

name is not uint16_t. It's an array of bytes, uint8_t name[].

For each byte, it's a pointer if byte[i] & 0xc0 == 0xc0 and the offset is (byte[i] & 0x3f) << 8) | byte[i+1]

So what you've shown there is a first byte is 0x20, the second byte is 11100000 which is the top half of a pointer.
